# Building inkscape beta with homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, inkscape

I was wondering if I could use homebrew to get inkscape's beta.  I know I can use it to get their current version with `brew cask install inkscape` but is there any way to get their beta?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `brew cask edit inkscape` to edit the formula that installs Inkscape.

For example, the latest version is found under:

```
http://alpha.inkscape.org/prereleases/Inkscape-latest.dmg
```

So, replace the contents of the file with:

```
cask 'inkscape' do
  version :latest
  sha256 :no_check

  url "http://alpha.inkscape.org/prereleases/Inkscape-latest.dmg"
  name 'Inkscape'
  homepage 'https://inkscape.org/'

  depends_on x11: true

  app 'Inkscape.app'
  binary "#{appdir}/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape"

  zap trash: '~/.inkscape-etc'
end
```

Save it and run `brew cask install inkscape`.

The specific change needed for "latest" versions is the `:latest` keyword. Also, you are skipping checksum verification with `:no_check`. Hence, be careful about what you are downloading.

Comment: Note that this is untested as I don't have a Mac to test with now. Please verify and let me know.

Comment: This answer saved my day!